# Connecting A Second Site To Current SQL Database

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

Ok - long story short.

Have an e-comm site hosted on Windows VPS using SQL Server 2005, site been up for years and works just fine.

I am now trying to set up a new site hosted on another Windows VPS Server that will share the same database.

Both sites are using classic asp and I have put up a duplicate page to each server that has a simple SQL query to display back a product name on screen.

On the new site I get the 500 error listed below:

> GET /testConnection.asp |49|800a0bb9|Arguments_are_of_the_wrong_type__are_out_of_acceptable_range__or_are_in_conflict_with_one_another.

Line 49 in the code is:

> rsProdDetail.Open SQL, cnn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

As I mentioned the page is identical on the 2 servers. The adovbs.inc is there and the path for the file include is correct on the new server.

Where do I look next?

Comment: Can the new VPS see the SQL server? All firewall rules the same?

Comment: Yes firewall is set to allow new VPS IP access.

Comment: Is there a way of verifying this?

Comment: Is SQL using an ODBC connection that's not defined on the second server? (Not sure why that would produce that error, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
rsProdDetail.Open SQL, cnn, 0, 1, 1
```

to see if the ADO constants are defined correctly ?

Comment: Tried your line of code and it has produced the same 500 error.